# adding new columns in a dataset with for loop

Tags: r

I want to add a new column  in data.frame "ref" using a for loop, if
`ref$chr==seg$chr & ref$Start < seg$End & ref$End < seg$Start`.

The new column should have colnames with unique(seg$ID)

## input

```
 ref <- read.table(text="
        Gene     chr  Start End 
        Gm12724   4  1000   1105    
        Gm12724   4  1254   1369    
        Usp17lc   7  5004   5412
        Lingo1    7  5698   5789
        Sart3     7  5987   6041
        Olfr978   4  1452   1564
    ", header=T)

  seg <- read.table(text="
        ID      chr Start   End     Xp
        S8411     4  989    1258   0.312
        S8411     4  1300   1800   0.144
        S8411     7  5641   6874   0.136
        S8413     4  1307   1360  -1.999
",header=T)
```

I used the following script for this but end up with a new column with all NAs

```
#select unique ID from seg
tmp_id <- unique(seg$ID)
tmp.value <- rep(NA,nrow(ref))

for (i in 1:length(tmp_id)){
     seg.tmp <- seg[which(seg$ID==tmp_id[i]),]
        for(j in 1:nrow(ref)){
            index <- which(ref$chr[j]==seg$chr & 
                     ref$Start[j] < seg$End & ref$End[j] < seg$Start)
                      if(length(index)==1){
                         tmp.value[j] <- seg$seg.mean[index]
                    
                }
        }
        ref <- cbind(ref,tmp.value)
    }
```

## expected output

```
ref <- read.table(" 
        Gene    chr   Start End   S8411  S8413
        Gm12724   4  1000   1105  0.312     NA
        Gm12724   4  1294   1369  0.144     -1.999
        Usp17lc   7  5004   5412    NA       NA
        Lingo1    7  5698   5789  0.136     NA
        Sart3     7  5987   6041  0.136     NA
        Olfr978   4  1452   1564   0.144    NA
",header=T)
```

Comment: Your inner loop does not seem to use `j`. You probably want to look into `merge` and perhaps "rolling joins" from the `data.table` package.

Comment: @Frank wouldn't it be possible to do it with for loop?

Comment: Sure, it can be done in a loop. I just meant that there might be ready-made solutions here. New problem: now I notice that you effectively are not using `i`, since `seg.tmp` is not used after it's created :)

Comment: I'm not sure what's your exact desired output is but you could also try `library(data.table);
setkey(setDT(ref), chr, Start, End);
setkey(setDT(seg), chr, Start, End);
foverlaps(ref, seg)`